# MVVM: Decouple Model from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, model, unity-container, prism, viewmodel

I've just started learning WPF MVVM using Prism and Unity.
Decoupling the view from the viewmodel works pretty well, but I don't get how wire up my viewmodel and my model.
I doesn't feel right to just create a new EntityObject right in my viewmodel. I have already skim-read the WAF BookLibrary sample but it is quite bulky and adds a lot of extra stuff around the essential part (binding between view and viewmodel), and the Prism docs don't say a word (as far as I read it) about viewmodel - model interaction.

Does anyone know a good source that explains how to use viewmodel and model in a clean way or can me give some advise?

Best Regards

Jay

Comment: Come on, there has to be an end somewhere, otherwise you might as well cast all types to `dynamic`.

Comment: @Will: I think he is look more for composition advice as opposed to stretching everything out into generics. Composition is one of the harder concepts to grasp at first for a lot of people as you have to know in detail how your application is going to fit together.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everyone will have their own opinions on this. Personally I don't mind using the model directly in the view model. For me, the whole idea of a view model is to extend your model in such a way that it can be consumed by a view.

A simple example of this would be person object, It would have model properties like like name and age for instance. When I get to the view model stage I may add properties to it like visibility which would not make sense on the model proper.

Another point to note is I would consider a model to be the data and the view model to be the context. So you may have a "Card" View Model for a person but you may also have a "List Item" view model that represents the same model in a different context, with different view model specific properties.

I do tend to make my models up using interfaces where relevant and use Inversion of control to inject them into the view model, that way the only thing my view model actually knows is that it needs an IPerson and that it will be provided in the constructor.

As I said other people will have different ideas, all are correct and its up to you to work out which one suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I starting to realize that there is no golden path for implementing MVVM and loose coupling.

Comment: @Jay: Nope there ain't. Everyone will have there own idea's on how it is done. I find it best to think from the view down. The that way the view will determine the vm contents and the vm will determine how the model is made up. Basically fold out functionality into lower levels where it makes sense. If your vm has a first name and surname, they are candidates to be pushed into the model, where as a method called NavigateToSomePage wouldn't make sense outside of the ViewModel.

Comment: @Jay: Also, it is worth nothing that a model is just a lair, it can be one or more classes and a view model is simply a grouping of one or more of these classes wrapped and extended in the context of the view. What that means is your details view model may pull from several classes in your model layer, there is not a 1 to 1 relationship between the model and the view model and nor should there be.

Comment: I just love "For me, the whole idea of a view model is to extend your model in such a way that it can be consumed by a view"- Such a great way of explaining a VM pragmatically.

Comment: @RichardOD:Thanks :) Once I got that concept in my head MVVM become a whole lot easier to work with.... and a lot more fun!